# Pricipale curvatures for the graph of a function

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ smooth (of class $C^2$), the surface $S$ defined by  $$S=\{(x,y,f(x,y)) : (x,y)\in U \}$$

So we can compute the principal curvatures of $S$ in terms of partial derivative of $f$. these exist for example in the book of Do Carmo.

I am looking for a reference that gives the expression of the principal curvatures of the hypersurface defined as the graph of a function for a higher dimension n>3.

$U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$, so we have one chart that parametrize the hypersurface $$S=\{(X,f(X)) : X\in U\}$$

Comment: The principal curvatures are more or less the eigenvalue of the second fundamental form $A$. While $A$ can be expressed using derivatives of $f$, I doubt if the eigenvalues has an explicit form.

Comment: @ArcticChar thanks,  as we can do this for a surface of 2-dimension  by using the local chart we can obtain this expression in the higher dimension  and this is the heart of my question

Comment: But in dimension 2 you have the quadratic formula to solve for the eigenvalues. In dimensions 3 and 4 the analogous formulas are totally unwieldy, and in dimensions 5 and higher there is nothing. And note that doCarmo does not in fact give formulas for the principal curvatures themselves.